# Ordering array with hierarchy by score, possibly using lodash. (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am a bit stuck on this one: I have a array of objects ordered according to a hierarchy (`parent_id`), something as follow:

```
let myArray = [
 { id: 1, parent_id: null, score: 20, type: 1 },
 { id: 12, parent_id: 1, score: 25, type: 2 },
 { id: 23, parent_id: 12, score: 55, type: 3 },
 { id: 35, parent_id: 12, score: 25, type: 3 },
 { id: 10, parent_id: null, score: 75, type: 1 },
 { id: 25, parent_id: 10, score: 15, type: 2 },
 { id: 100, parent_id: 25, score: 88, type: 3 }
]
```

Now I would like to maintain the hierarchy order, but also order the elements by score to obtain something like this:

```
let expected = [
 { id: 10, parent_id: null, score: 75, type: 1 },
 { id: 25, parent_id: 10, score: 15, type: 2 },
 { id: 100, parent_id: 25, score: 88, type: 3 },
 { id: 1, parent_id: null, score: 20, type: 1 },
 { id: 12, parent_id: 1, score: 25, type: 2 },
 { id: 23, parent_id: 12, score: 55, type: 3 },
 { id: 35, parent_id: 12, score: 25, type: 3 },
]
```

I am writing pretty inefficient code with nested `foreach` that almost work, but nor quite yet. I was wondering if there was a neater solution. (pretty sure there is, but too smart for me).
Also in my code I am relaying on the `type` attribute, but ideally I would not use it for sorting.

Note: this data is just an example, the real array is bigger and the number of children for each parent vary.

Since my explanation is not great we can think of hierarchy in this way
`type:1` -> Country
`type:2` -> State
`type:3` -> City

So I need to order by score `desc` like this

```
- Country
  - State
    - City 
    - City
  - State
    - City
 - Country and so on...
```

Thank you to anyone who is willing to land me an hand,

Comment: I'm confused, how do you maintain parent_id order whilst maintaining score order?

Comment: why is id 10 before 1?

Comment: yeah.. I don't know how to explain it nicely. I think we can put it this way (which is a bit what I am doing with my ugly solution) Pick the highest score for elements of type 1, then pick the highest score of type 2 that has 1 as a parent id, then put all type 3s under type2, ordered by score, and so on and so forth...

Comment: @NenadVracar, if that's the case why `id:23` is below `id:1`

Comment: I guess because there is also `parent_id` is `id` of previous element, rule first.

Comment: @kgangadhar because of the hierarchy, I don't want to order only by score. `id:23` is after `id:1` because it's a grandchildren of `id:1`

Comment: why do you have double id 25?

Comment: my bad, typo, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single sort does not work, because of the parent children relation which is not respected while sorting the data.

This approach works in three parts:

1. Sort data by `score`, because the following tree is build in insertation order.
2. Build a tree with the given relationship.
3. Traverse the tree and get sorted flat data back.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, parent_id: null, score: 20, type: 1 }, { id: 12, parent_id: 1, score: 25, type: 2 }, { id: 23, parent_id: 12, score: 55, type: 3 }, { id: 35, parent_id: 12, score: 25, type: 3 }, { id: 10, parent_id: null, score: 75, type: 1 }, { id: 25, parent_id: 10, score: 15, type: 2 }, { id: 100, parent_id: 25, score: 88, type: 3 }]
        .sort(function (a, b) { return b.score - a.score; }),
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.id] = { data: a, children: o[a.id] && o[a.id].children };
            if (a.parent_id === root) {
                r.push(o[a.id]);
            } else {
                o[a.parent_id] = o[a.parent_id] || {};
                o[a.parent_id].children = o[a.parent_id].children || [];
                o[a.parent_id].children.push(o[a.id]);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, null),                               // null is the root value of parent_id
    sorted = tree.reduce(function traverse(r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.data, (a.children || []).reduce(traverse, []));
    }, [])

console.log(sorted);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wow, thank you. For some reason it doesn't want to work on my real set of data, but I guess you put me very much in the right direction

Comment: maybe `id` or `parent_id` is different named.

Comment: no that is the same, score is `percentage_score` but that it's easy to replace, must be something in there, like maybe some entities don't have the full hierarchy, or some empty value messing up... I am using test data that might be not very clean. Somehow both the tree and the sorted are coming back empty, I'll figure it out hopefully

Comment: then it could be the wrong root value of `parent_id`. actually it's `null`, at the second parameter.

Comment: ah it could be, some of the `type:1` have `parent_id:0` instead of `parent_id:null`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I end up changing `if (a.parent_id === root)` to `if (a.parent_id === root || a.parent_id === 0)`, seems to work now, got to test it a bit more. Actually I might be able to get the parent_id always set a `0`, null is a bit trickier. But thank you for your help. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165150/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-mikey).

Answer (score 1):

I changed your data set to make the example easier to understand. And I used several functions to sort the data:

```js
let arr = [
  {country: 'USA', state:'Washington', city:'Washington DC'},
  {country: 'USA', state:'Washington', city:'Boston'},
  {country: 'USA', state:'California', city:'San Diego'},
  {country: 'Brazil', state:'North', city:'C'},
  {country: 'Brazil', state:'North', city:'B'},
  {country: 'Brazil', state:'South', city:'A'},
  {country: 'Turkey', state:'East', city:'f'},
  {country: 'Turkey', state:'East', city:'e'},
  {country: 'Turkey', state:'West', city:'d'},
];

let expected = [
  {country: 'Brazil', state:'North', city:'B'},
  {country: 'Brazil', state:'North', city:'C'},
  {country: 'Brazil', state:'South', city:'A'},
  {country: 'Turkey', state:'East', city:'e'},
  {country: 'Turkey', state:'East', city:'f'},
  {country: 'Turkey', state:'West', city:'d'},
  {country: 'USA', state:'California', city:'San Diego'},
  {country: 'USA', state:'Washington', city:'Boston'},
  {country: 'USA', state:'Washington', city:'Washington DC'},
];

const sortByCountry = arr => {
  return arr.sort((city1,city2) => city1.country > city2.country);
};

const sortByState = arr =>
  arr.sort(
    (city1,city2) => {
      // Don't compare when countries differ.
      if (city1.country !== city2.country) return 0;
      return city1.state > city2.state;
    }
  );

const sortByCity = arr =>
  arr.sort(
    (city1,city2) => {
      // Don't compare when countries or states differ.
      if (city1.country !== city2.country) return 0;
      if (city1.state !== city2.state) return 0;
      return city1.city > city2.city;
    }
  );

let result = sortByCity(sortByState(sortByCountry(arr)));

console.log('------expected-----');
console.log(expected);
console.log('------result-----');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```